# why can't get input elements when add dynamic input by using jquery.find(":input")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

why can't get input elements when add dynamic input? but i can get input elements while not add dynamic input!

```js
$('#getInputBtn').click(function() {
  var myForm = $('#testForm').find(':input')
  console.log(myForm)
})

$('#addInputBtn').click(function() {
  var inputStr = '<div style="background: #F6F7F8; padding: 10px 0; margin-bottom: 10px;"><div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="form-item" style="width: 100%"><label for="nodeType" class="form-item-label-required col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 20px;line-height: 40px;text-align: right;">nodeType</label><input id="nodeType" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" required></input></div></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="form-item" style="width: 100%"><label for="areaType" class="form-item-label-required col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 20px;line-height: 40px;text-align: right;">areaType</label><input id="areaType" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" required></input></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="form-item" style="width: 100%"><label for="countType" class="form-item-label-required col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 20px;line-height: 40px;text-align: right;">countType</label><input id="countType" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" required></input></div></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="form-item" style="width: 100%"><label for="contractType" class="form-item-label-required col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 20px;line-height: 40px;text-align: right;">contractType</label><input id="contractType" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" required></input></div></div></div></div>'
  $('#small').html(inputStr)
})
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="testForm">
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-item" style="width: 100%">
        <label for="orgTypeList" class="form-item-label-required col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 20px;line-height: 40px;text-align: right;width: 16%;">orgType</label>
        <input id="orgTypeList" class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12" style="width: 84%" required readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="small"></div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-item" style="width: 100%">
        <label for="positionList" class="form-item-label form-item-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 20px;line-height: 40px;text-align: right;width: 16%;">position</label>
        <input id="positionList" class="ui-input col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 " style="width: 84%;" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-item" style="width: 100%">
        <label for="postList" class="form-item-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 20px;line-height: 40px;text-align: right;width: 16%;">post</label>
        <input id="postList" class="ui-input col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 tagsinput" style="width: 84%;" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<button id="getInputBtn">getInput</button>
<button id="addInputBtn">add Dynamic INPUT</button>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/qfwfqf/pen/bOgoxo)：

Comment: if yo want to find `input` element use `var myForm = $('#testForm').find('input')`

Comment: After some hours I figure it out what was the problem and unfortunately it is your input field id nodeType (use by jQuery internally for some purpose and that input field modifying it), yeah seriously, just change that id and it will work properly.

Comment: 1 other unnecessary thing is, remove input closing tag **</input>** from **inputStr**

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to:

```
$('#getInputBtn').click(function() {
    var myForm = $('#testForm :input');
    console.log(myForm);
});
```

It's working but I am not 100% sure why. I'll check and explain later. For now, you can at least fix your code.

Comment: After some hours I figure it out what was the problem and unfortunately it is your input field id **nodeType** (use by jQuery internally for some purpose and that input field modifying it), yeah seriously, just change that id and it will work properly.

Comment: @shajji It solved my problem perfectly.thank u for ur help!